# Add OnItemLongClickListener to groupie recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im trying to implement a long click listener for my groupie recycler list but I keep getting an error that its expecting a `Boolean` and it found `unit`. Can someone please point me in right direction?

Code for the adapter:

```
 private fun updateRecyclerView(items: List<Item>) {
    fun init() {
        recycler_view_people.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@PeopleFragment.context)
            adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>().apply {
                peopleSection = Section(items)
                add(peopleSection)
                setOnItemClickListener(onItemClick)
                setOnItemLongClickListener(onLongItemClick)
            }
        }
        shouldInitRecyclerView = false
    }

    fun updateItems() = peopleSection.update(items)

    if (shouldInitRecyclerView)
        init()
    else
        updateItems()
}
private val onItemClick = OnItemClickListener { item, view ->
    if (item is ModuleItem) {
        startActivity<ChatActivity>(
                AppConstants.GROUP_NAME to item.module.Code,
                AppConstants.GROUP_ID to item.modId
        )


    }
}
private val onLongItemClick = OnItemLongClickListener { item, view ->


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not made any mistakes, the problem is that the method requires a function to work and return so you just need some data in the method.

```
private val onLongItemClick = OnItemLongClickListener { item, view ->
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@PeopleFragment.context!!)
    builder.setMessage("Blah").show()
    true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a return type of boolean in your listeners.

`abstract boolean
    onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

> Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been clicked and held.